# How to properly move Rust Diesel query in a separate function?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I want to move the big shared query code with many joins to a separate function. I intend to preserve this as a lazy query which would be executed in the future in different places with `filter`, `limit` and other methods.

But it requires specifying a concrete return type, and it's huge and non-readable at all.

Then, I've tried to set return type as `impl QueryDsl` and `Box< impl QueryDsl>`.

```
fn users_query() -> impl QueryDsl {
     users_dsl
        .inner_join(...)
        .inner_join(...)
        .inner_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
}
```

Which is kind of compile, but when I try to use `filter` or `limit` it raises an errors:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `_: Sized`
   --> users/src/repository.rs:278:14
    |
278 |             .filter(users_table::id.eq(user_id.as_sql::<sql_types::Uuid>()))
    |              ^^^^^^
    |
    = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`site_users_view`)
    = note: required for `impl QueryDsl` to implement `FilterDsl<_>`
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl QueryDsl: Table` is not satisfied
   --> users/src/repository.rs:288:43
    |
288 |         let query = users_query().limit(limit.into());
    |                                           ^^^^^ the trait `Table` is not implemented for `impl QueryDsl`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Table`:
              Only<S>
              diesel_migrations::migration_harness::__diesel_schema_migrations::table
              pg::metadata_lookup::pg_namespace::table
              pg::metadata_lookup::pg_type::table
              schema::permissions::table
              schema::users::table
              addresses::table
              cities::table
            and 7 others
    = note: required for `impl QueryDsl` to implement `LimitDsl`
```

So, there is a question: How to properly move query in a separate function?

Comment: In my experience, there is a bunch of friendly and active people in https://gitter.im/diesel-rs/diesel, in case you might want to ask there as well. (Incidentally, stuff like this is why I ended up using straight up tokio-postgres :D)

Comment: Thanks, @user3139876! I've posted this question there, but didn't get some feedback. And generally speaking, the actual chat seems not really active.

Comment: I've checked out the tokio-postgress. It feels more kind low level, doesn't it?

Comment: Definitely. Low-level is fine for me personally, since I don't mind writing raw sql. Diesel development felt like 95% of the time spent trying to figure out wth the compiler is trying to say in its page-long error messages, 5% actual development...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @weiznich inside [Gitter Diesel channel](https://gitter.im/diesel-rs/diesel) answered that this way of using Diesel is not possible:

> Generally speaking: You cannot use impl … there as such return types do not allow you to specify all types correctly. You want to use one or more of the typealiases from diesel::dsl

And the return type should be described explicitly. The detailed guide could be found on "[Composing Applications](https://diesel.rs/guides/composing-applications.html)" guide.

In my case, the output type will be inside, so I move forward with code duplication for now.

Also, I've found out that if reuse of query inside single function it's possible to define such queries in anonymous function like:

```
let users_query = || {
     users_dsl
        .inner_join(...)
        .inner_join(...)
        .inner_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
        .left_join(...)
}
```